# what's the meaning of "analogy a go go" meaning

Tags: meaning

please tell me about the meaning of this sentence:

So, reader, it’ll be analogy-a-go-go from here on; strap in.

what the writer want to say?

Comment: You can find a definition of "a-go-go" [in the dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/a-go-go).

Answer (score 1):

The "-a-go-go" ending is a kind of cheesy American way of saying "a lot of". The writer is saying "there will be a lot of analogies from here on".